# How can I get Vim to indent all the lines in a list item - not just the second?

Tags: vim, formatting

The `n` option of Vim's `formatoptions` setting will indent the second line of a list item to match the indentation of the first line. However, the *third* and subsequent lines revert to no indentation, thus:

```
1. Doing a list. This is my list. I am writing
   a list. It's quite a long list. It's really
long. I can't believe how long it is. And
this just the first item!

2. Another list item.
```

I'd really like it to indent *all* the lines, like this:

```
1. Doing a list. This is my list. I am writing
   a list. It's quite a long list. It's really
   long. I can't believe how long it is. And
   this just the first item!

2. Another list item.
```

Is this possible, either using Vim's own options, a script, or an external formatting program, such as par?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think just setting 'autoindent' should fix that. It does for me.

```
set ai
```

Comment: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/vimfaq2html3.pl#14.4

Comment: Works for me too, and I feel stupid for not figuring it out myself, especially seeing as it's right there in the documentation for the 'n' setting! Thanks.

Comment: @akira Yup. I am an idiot. I think my confusion was that because Vim was indenting the second line, I presumed that I had `autoindent` switched on already, and that the behaviour described in the question was the designed behaviour. I do think the manual could be worded more clearly, though, to benefit idiots such as myself. :)

Comment: See @akira's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/236379/15613) for a more in-depth solution.

Comment: @Rich, although I am reluctant to call myself stupid, I did go down the same path as you... Thanks for the question and answer.

Answer (score 6):

in your case i would do this:

```
 :set autoindent       " just for interactive indenting (see answer of @Rich) 
 :set fo+=2n           " :help fo-table
 :set tw=47            " your text shall wrap at xyz
```

(the `tw=47`is important for ..) and then reformat a paragraph by pressing <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>

note: i couldnt reindent the paragrap with <kbd>=</kbd> either, maybe someone else figured that out.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of the **`a p`** motion to format lines. I always use the right brace, which is similar. Don't forget you can add a count, for example, format the next three paragraphs: **`g q 3 }`**.